# How to input different distances in different routes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, distance, geolocation

Generally, Travel time requires travel time and mode, then it shows the distance covered by the given time. But I want to input different distances in different routes surrounding the station point location. Is this possible to input different distance location in different routes? I'm attaching a conceptual image to understand. [image]

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do you wish to input a distance of, for example 1km, and find all points on the network that are 1km from the given center point?

Comment: @Matt  I want to input individual distance point for individual route. how can I? and then want to connect all given points. Is this possible through QGIS?